# Converting string to date and finding time difference

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to convert a string to a date time object and then subtract the difference between 2 dates. However I keep getting an invalid pointer warning. The date is formatted 20131209 02:34. My code is below

```
NSDateFormatter *df =[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"YYYYMMDD HH:MM"];
NSDate *currTime = [df dateFromString:self.currentTime];
NSDate *predicTime =[df dateFromString:self.predictedTime];
NSTimeInterval newtime=[predicTime timeIntervalSinceDate:currTime];
```

Comment: YYdd HH:MM is this valid date format ?

Comment: `[df setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd hh:mm"];`

Comment: Are `self.predictedTime` and `self.currentTime` valid pointers to `NSString` instances?

Comment: yes i am stepping through the debugger and the values are there

Comment: On which line exactly do you get the warning? What is the complete warning message?

Comment: on the line where i instantiate currTime. In the debugger it just says invalid pointer next to it and sets the value to nil

Comment: @TroyBarrios: what warning message ?

Answer (score 1):

Your date format was incorrect `[df setDateFormat:@"YYYYMMDD HH:MM"];` I assumed that your strings are valid !

Try :

```
NSDateFormatter *df =[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd HH:mm"];  // 24hr format, for 12hr format use 'hh'
NSDate *currTime = [df dateFromString:@"20131209 02:34"];
NSDate *predicTime =[df dateFromString:@"20131209 04:34"];
NSTimeInterval newtime=[predicTime timeIntervalSinceDate:currTime];
```

Comment: More probably "HH" for 24-hour time.

Comment: 24 hr format. I am using an api and that is the format that was given

Comment: @Maulik answer is correct.  [Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/cocoa-factory/7869647) to demonstrate.  It logs "dif = 7200.0" to the console.

Answer (score 0):

try out this code

```
 NSDateFormatter *df =[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
 [df setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd hh:mm"];
 NSDate *currTime = [df dateFromString:self.currentTime];
 NSDate *predicTime =[df dateFromString:self.predictedTime];
 NSTimeInterval newtime=[predicTime timeIntervalSinceDate:currTime];
```